# How to skip a command in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am running a simple batch script to start 2 programs. How do I have added a line which checks if the program is running. How can I then skip the startup of the program and move onto the next line.

```
@echo off

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Test123.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Test123.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo program is running

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test123"
start Test123.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test123"
start OtherTest123.exe

exit
```

Comment: Do you have a typo on the second sentence - because you have line that checks if a program is running ? And now you want to skip a line if the errorlevel is `0` ?

Comment: Yes I want to skip the line if the errorlevel is 0. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: with if command you can use brackets to put a few commands if a condition is faced. Haven't you tried this?

Comment: I'm not sure how to. I have not used batch files a lot. I tried looking for a command that skips the next few lines but can't find anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use labels and GOTO to control the flow through the file like this:

```
@echo off

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Test123.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Test123.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" GOTO nextprogram

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test123"
start Test123.exe

:nextprogram
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test123"
start OtherTest123.exe

exit
```

See more detailed description of goto here: https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html

Comment: goto will slow down the script if with brackets is a better option.

Comment: You are right, brackets is the better option, if you are concerned about pereformance and especially if the batch file is very long. Labels have to be searched in the batch file. The order is top to down. It resumes searching at the top of the file if the end was reached without finding it. The longer the file the more time it takes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @user3154458 will work, but for readability and maintenance, I would recommend a code block. Also, using `CD /D` will ensure that the default drive is also changed at the same time.

```
@echo off
PUSHD "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test123"

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Test123.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Test123.exe">NUL
if NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (start Test123.exe)
start OtherTest123.exe

POPD    
exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest perhaps doing it like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Test123" 2>Nul||Exit /B
TaskList|FindStr/I "\<Test123.exe\>">Nul&&(Start "" "OtherTest123.exe")||Start "" "Test123.exe"
```

Comment: I am confident that this will work, @Compo. However, it take a few brain cycles to unpack. That is costly for comprehension and maintenance.

Comment: I like it better with the newline. I am not sure it reduces the thinking required.

Comment: Let's see what the OP has to say about the complexity of the solutions.